# Not Able to Read the property value in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, el

I am running a java web application on Java 6 and Spring 3.0.

I have properties file used by the web application and is loaded by the spring framework on server start.

`config.properties`

```
url=http://www.url.com
test.url=http://www.test.com
dev.url=http://www.dev.com
```

I have requirement to use the properties values in java and jsp code. I am able to access the value in java using annotations provided in spring 3.0 : `@Value("${test.url}")`

To use the properties in JSP, I am trying to load the properties into servlet context, so that the properties can be referenced in the JSP directly

```
servletContext.setAttribute("props", properties);
```

In my jsp, when i print `${props}`, it results the following ...

```
{url=http://www.url.com,test.url=http://www.test.com,dev.url=http://www.dev.com}
```

But when i print `${props.test.url}`, it prints nothing (the same works fine for `${props.url}`).

Is this an issue or am i doing something wrong. How can i get the `${props.test.url}` work in jsp?

Answer (score 6):

Your EL syntax isn't quite right.  Try this:

```
${props['test.url']}
```

The `${props.url}` syntax works due to a convenience syntax for addressing the contents of a map as though it were a javabean property, but it doesn't work when the map key itself contains a `.`, in which case you should use the full map-lookup syntax shown above.

Comment: thank you very much. That worked. I am still suprised...how it did not strike me :(

Comment: You should accept answers when they solve your problem, Johnny! Thanks skaffman.